# PowerShell output is saying no

Tags: powershell, script

I wrote this PowerShell script to read two big text file based on the following model:

ID "Text", the script read both text file and is supposed to compare them and tell me if the line exist in both text file or not.

However, every time I launch the script no matter what I do the script is just saying No: [image: error message I suppose]

Here is the script I wrote:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Ouvrir une boîte de dialogue pour choisir le premier fichier
$openFileDialog1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
$openFileDialog1.Filter = "Fichiers texte (*.txt)|*.txt"
$openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$filePath1 = $openFileDialog1.FileName

if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($filePath1)) {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Aucun fichier choisi pour le premier fichier, arrêt du script.")
    return
}

# Ouvrir une boîte de dialogue pour choisir le deuxième fichier
$openFileDialog2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$openFileDialog2.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
$openFileDialog2.Filter = "Fichiers texte (*.txt)|*.txt"
$openFileDialog2.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$filePath2 = $openFileDialog2.FileName

if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($filePath2)) {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Aucun fichier choisi pour le deuxième fichier, arrêt du script.")
    return
}

# Lire les fichiers texte ligne par ligne et ignorer les commentaires
$file1Content = Get-Content -Path $filePath1 | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^\s*//' }
$file2Content = Get-Content -Path $filePath2 | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^\s*//' }

# Initialiser une variable pour stocker les résultats
$results = @()

# Comparer chaque ligne des deux fichiers
foreach ($line1 in $file1Content) {
    $id1, $text1 = $line1 -split ' ', 2
    $found = $false

    foreach ($line2 in $file2Content) {
        $id2, $text2 = $line2 -split ' ', 2

        if ($id1 -eq $id2) {
            $found = $true
            if ($text1 -eq $text2) {
                $results += "${id1}: Identique"
            } else {
                $results += "${id1}: Différent"
            }
            break
        }
    }

    if (-not $found) {
        $results += "${id1}: Non trouvé dans le deuxième fichier"
    }
}

# Vérifier les IDs du deuxième fichier qui ne sont pas dans le premier fichier
foreach ($line2 in $file2Content) {
    $id2, $text2 = $line2 -split ' ', 2

    if ($file1Content -notcontains $line2) {
        $results += "${id2}: Non trouvé dans le premier fichier"
    }
}

# Convertir les résultats en une seule chaîne de caractères
$resultsString = [string]::Join("`r`n", $results)

# Afficher une boîte de dialogue avec les résultats
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($resultsString, "Résultats de la comparaison", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information)
```

Write-output and write-host debug provide no useful info whatsoever.

I'm currently on Windows 10 21H2 version and last version of PowerShell.

What is wrong with my script?

Comment: I suggest to add more output to the script to find out which line prints "No", then check the offending command and maybe add more output to show variable values that lead to this result.

Comment: it works perfectly for me, except for the messagebox which causes Powershell to hang. Simply replace the last line buy `$resultsstring` to get the results on the standard output

Comment: The last line already use $resultsstring ? I don't understand your point